# Monetizing Android App

Tags: android, admob

My Android App has been published on Google Play, can I click on the ads of my App, shown to me when I open the App? I have heard that clicking on the ads of your own App is against the policy of admob and that your admob account can be suspended, though I am not too sure. If anyone could please guide me on this, I would be very thankful to him.

Comment: Do the proper thing with that, and here too: delete the question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of an advertising network, not programming.

Answer (score 4):

yes, you **can** click the ads on your own apps
yes, you should **not** do it because it's against the policy of admob and your admob account will be disabled. Either on purpose or by accident

Answer (score 3):

Clicking on the ads of your own App is against the policy of admob and that your admob account can be suspended. Dont try to click on your add using your account otherwise your account will be suspend for 1 month.I already done this and my account suspended for 1 month.

Answer (score 2):

> Publishers may not click their own ads or use any means to inflate impressions and/or clicks artificially, including manual methods. Testing your own ads by clicking on them is not allowed.

To test your own ads see:
[Android](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#faq) | [iOS](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#faq) | [WP](https://developers.google.com/admob/wp/quick-start#faq)

Source: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860#Invalid_clicks